# is canopy depth the same as the length of the canopy field of the `fetchMerkleTree()` method from umi

Tags: umi

I am trying to fetch the canopy depth and would love to know if it's the same as the length of the canopy field returned when I call the `fetchMerkleTree()` method from umi.

Answer (score 4):

The `canopy` array inside the `MerkleTreeAccount` object stores all of the nodes within the canopy depth excluding the root node.

For instance, if a tree has a canopy depth of 3, then its canopy array will contain `2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 = 14` nodes.

```
                    X
            _______/ \_______
           /                 \
          O                   O
      ___/ \___           ___/ \___
     /         \         /         \
    O           O       O           O
   / \         / \     / \         / \
  O   O       O   O   O   O       O   O
```

This can be generalised by the following formula:

```
size = 2^(depth + 1) - 2
```

Which means we can compute the depth using:

```
depth = log2(size + 2) - 1
```

Or in your case:

```
const merkleTreeAccount = await fetchMerkleTree(umi, merkleTree);
const canopyDepth = Math.log2(merkleTreeAccount.canopy.length + 2) - 1;
```